# Get the POST data back on Web API

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API server that runs in c#. The httpget methods works perfectly, but I am too new to Web Api to get the post to work, and my searches that I've done is a bit fruitless.

This is my HttpPost in the ApiController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool UploadLogs(UploadLogsIn logs)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

This is the model

```
public class UploadLogsIn
{
    public byte[] logData { get; set; }
    public int aLogs { get; set; }
}
```

In a c++ Application I try to post data to this method. I'm using Curl to do the post

```
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.56.109:9615/api/WebApiService/UploadLogs");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, R"({"UploadLogsIn": [{"aLogs: 10}]})");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

When I debug the Web Api, the method gets hit, but the parameter does not contain any data.

**UPDATE**
With wireshark, this is the information that is sent

```
POST /api/WebApiService/UploadLogs HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.56.109:9615
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Form item: "{"UploadLogsIn": [{"aLogs: 10}]}" = ""
```

**END UPDATE**

If I add a header

```
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");
```

then my parameter is null.

The Wireshark dump for this is

```
POST /api/WebApiService/UploadLogs HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.56.109:9615
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
charsets: utf-8
Content-Length: 32

Line-based text data: application/json
{"UploadLogsIn": [{"aLogs: 10}]}
```

I'm sure there is something dumb that I do not do right. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Data being sent is not well formed JSON data. Review how you are constructing the JSON object. The classes do not match the json being sent

Comment: I've changed the string to `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, R"({"UploadLogsIn": [{"aLogs": 10}]})"); Is there still something wrong in the JSON? The result stays the same at this stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the class you want and the data being sent.

Your desired class looks like this

```
public class UploadLogsIn {
    public byte[] logData { get; set; }
    public int aLogs { get; set; }
}
```

But the data being sent looks like this

```
{"UploadLogsIn": [{"aLogs": 10}]}
```

Which when deserialized looks like this

```
public class UploadLogsIn
{
    public int aLogs { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public IList<UploadLogsIn> UploadLogsIn { get; set; }
}
```

See the difference?

To get the model to bind to this action

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UploadLogs([FromBody]UploadLogsIn logs) {
    return true;
}
```

The data sent would have to look like this

```
{"aLogs": 10}
```

Comment: The actual problem that I had with the null is because I used invalid information in the byte[]. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *[FromBody]* in *UploadLogs*

```
   [HttpPost]
    public bool UploadLogs([FromBody]UploadLogsIn logs)
      {
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that. I've added that, as well as adding `        [ResponseType(typeof(UploadLogsIn))]` below `[HttpPost]`

Comment: with no effect ? Still same issue ? Try to use fiddler to sniff what has been send in request body

Comment: I'm using Wireshark. I will edit my question to add that as well

Comment: Try this... instead of `public bool UploadLogs([FromBody]UploadLogsIn logs)` try with `public bool UploadLogs([FromBody]object logs)`.
And then using debugger check that object.

Comment: Try to use Request.Content , Request.Headers and Request.RequestUri for debugging the result. That should give you at least a chance to pinpoint the source of the issue.

Comment: @arcticwhite There is no information on logs in debug. Evaluate to {object}

Comment: @Vladimir look at the JSON being sent. Is it well formed? Start there.

Answer (score 1):

I also added [FromBody] to my input data.

I looked at what [swagger](https://swagger.io/) suggested for me to send data in a post statement:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{     "EmailAddress": "string",    "Title": "string",     Message": "string",     "OriginId": 0,     "Name": "string"   }'  http://wfadpqa.sidmar.be/SecureIt.Service/api/contact'
```